# Download File from S3 using Java AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I would like to be able to download a file from an S3 bucket to my local computer using a Java Lambda Function. I have written the code below in a Java Lambda Function which is able to download the file to the /tmp directory of AWS. But then what are my options? How do I get the file downloaded to my local computer? Thank you.

```
    S3TransferManager transferManager = S3TransferManager.create();
     
    DownloadFileRequest downloadFileRequest = DownloadFileRequest.builder()
                    .getObjectRequest(b -> b.bucket(bucketName).key(key))
                    .addTransferListener(LoggingTransferListener.create())
                    .destination(Paths.get(downloadedFileWithPath))
                    .build();

    FileDownload downloadFile = transferManager.downloadFile(downloadFileRequest);

    CompletedFileDownload downloadResult = downloadFile.completionFuture().join();
    logger.info("Content length [{}]", downloadResult.response().contentLength());
    return downloadResult.response().contentLength();
```

Comment: Why do you need to use Lambda?  A small Java program can do this on your local machine.  The AWS CLI can do this on your local machine.   A Lambda will not be able to write directly to your local machine without something else like a browser being used.

Comment: The Lambda can not directly access your local PC.  You could have the Lambda return (either as redirect, or some sort of application specific data) a presigned URL for the S3 object that you use to download the content on your local machine.

Comment: If the Lambda function can access the object but you cannot locally *and* you cannot get suitable AWS credentials locally, then the Lambda function could generate and return a [pre-signed URL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/examples-s3-presign.html) to the object. You can then use that URL to download the object in your browser or using curl/wget.

Answer (score 0):

I can provide with code example that will allows you to download files from AWS Lambda.

```java
public class Handler implements RequestHandler<Object, APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent> {

    public APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent handleRequest(Object input, Context context) {

        // put here goes your s3 code
        
        // This is how to form file upload response:
        APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent response = new APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent();
        try {
            response.setStatusCode(200);
            response.setBody(Files.readString(Paths.get(path), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            response.setHeaders(Map.of(
                    "Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + key + "\"",
                    "Content-Length", String.valueOf(downloadResult.response().contentLength())
            ));
            return response;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            response.setStatusCode(500);
        }
        return response;
    }
}
```

```
implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-lambda-java-events:3.11.0'
```

Modify that as you wish, but consider next for your file distributions:

1. Response is only allowing body to be `String`. This is not optimal and just an example. You should use `InputStream` instead in real application. For that you need to looks for the lib that can produce HTTP responses from input stream.
2. By analogy you shouldn't save file from S3 to file, you can use `S3Client` to get `InputStream`, buffer it and pass to  HTTP response.
3. Don't stream file via AWS Lambda and use pre-signed URL as @jarmod proposed. This will require you downloading file manually though.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the responses. I was able to generate a pre-signed URL for the object in the S3 bucket using the Java function given here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/examples-s3-presign.html

The code I used:

```
    try (S3Presigner presigner = S3Presigner.create()) {

        GetObjectRequest objectRequest=GetObjectRequest.builder()
                .bucket(bucketName)
                .key(keyName)
                .build();

        GetObjectPresignRequest presignRequest = 
                 GetObjectPresignRequest.builder()
                .signatureDuration(Duration.ofMinutes(10))
                .getObjectRequest(objectRequest)
                .build();

        PresignedGetObjectRequest presignedRequest = 
                presigner.presignGetObject(presignRequest);
        logger.info("Presigned URL: [{}]", 
                presignedRequest.url().toString());
        logger.info("HTTP method: [{}]", 
                presignedRequest.httpRequest().method());

        return presignedRequest.url().toExternalForm();
    }
}
```

I was then able to download the file by putting the the pre-signed URL in the browser.